# Load amchart on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

My code looks like:

```
var check = parametrTable.length -1;
var data = [];
$.each(parametrTable, function(i, x) { // NOTE: x = parametrTable[i]
    $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(j, d) {
            data[j] = data[j] || {};
            data[j]["count" + i] = d.count;
            if (i == 0) {
                data[j].category = d.column;
            }
        });
        if(i == check){
                       loadChart(data);
                   }
    });
});
```

This part generate data from my amchart, next if 'i' == 'check' (end of .each loop) i send generate data to function 'loadChart' with parametr 'data'.
Code for my function:

```
    AmCharts.ready(function() {
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();

    chart.dataProvider = data;
    chart.categoryField = "category";
    chart.startDuration = 1;
    chart.type = "serial";


    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
        categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90; 
        categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 1;
        categoryAxis.insie = true;
        categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.title = "title";
        valueAxis.axisAlpha = 1;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    for (i=0;i<data.length;++i) {
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.valueField = "count"+i+"";
        graph.balloonText = "[[value]]";
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.type = "smoothedLine";
        graph.lineAlpha = 1;
        graph.connect = true;
        graph.lineThickness = '2';
        //graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        chart.addGraph(graph);
    }

        chart.write('chartdiv');
    });
```

On my page i have div with id = 'chartdiv'. When I check in the function the values in the table (data) its look ok, but my chart does not regenerate. :( When I skip

```
AmCharts.ready(function() {
```

chart is generated, but not all the values. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your actual data, but it seems that the issue is how you crate your graphs. Right now you are creating a separate graph for **each** data point in your data. That does not seem right. You should create for each item in `parametrTable`:

```
for (i=0;i<=check;++i) {
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.valueField = "count"+i+"";
        graph.balloonText = "[[value]]";
        graph.bullet = "round";
        graph.type = "smoothedLine";
        graph.lineAlpha = 1;
        graph.connect = true;
        graph.lineThickness = '2';
        //graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        chart.addGraph(graph);
}
```

Additionally, jQuery AJAX calls are asynchronous. Meaning that the your `.each()` cycle completes **before** actual data is loaded.

You need to keep separate iterator to keep track of number of loaded items. I.e.:

```
var check = parametrTable.length -1;
var loaded = 0;
var data = [];
$.each(parametrTable, function(i, x) { // NOTE: x = parametrTable[i]
    $.getJSON("myurlwithparametr", function(json) {
        loaded++;
        $.each(json, function(j, d) {
            data[j] = data[j] || {};
            data[j]["count" + i] = d.count;
            if (i == 0) {
                data[j].category = d.column;
            }
        });
        if(loaded == check){
           loadChart(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that amchart loaded earlier than the data. Sometimes displays a single value, sometimes not. If you look at the table loaded into the console (console.info (data)), it looks ok. The solution would be to create a graph after loading the data, but how to do it ..

Comment: Transferred data look ok, but the chart's not. It looks as if the chart itself does not answer some random data. Sometimes the missing category, sometimes one of the graph. It looks as if it was never ready because when I add "AmCharts.ready (function ())", nothing is displayed.